# How do I make a loop advance using onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, and I'm totally stumped.

I'm writing a program that is supposed to display a basic series of multiple-choice questions. You see a question, you click one of the answers, and you move on to the next question.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to display one question, then display the next question when the user clicks one of the buttons. Nothing happens when I click a button. What's going wrong?

```
        // progress meter
        var progress = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) progress.push("0");

        var i = 0;
        display(0);

        // display questions
        function display(i) {
            var prg_string;
            for (var j = 0; j < progress.length; j++) prg_string += progress[j];
            document.write(
                "<div id = 'background'>"
                    + "<div id = 'progress'>" + progress + "</div>"
                    + "<div id = 'title'>-JogNog Test v1-<br></br>" + tower + "</div>"
                    + "<div id = 'question'>" + questions[i].text + "</div>"
                    + "<div id = 'stats'>Level " + level + "/" + total_levels + " Question " + (i + 1) + "/" + questions.length + "</div>"
                + "</div>"
            );

            document.write("<button id = 'answer1' onclick = 'next(questions[i].answers[0].correct)'>" + questions[i].answers[0].text + "</button>");
            if (questions[i].answers.length > 0)
                document.write("<button id = 'answer2' onclick = 'next(questions[i].answers[1].correct)'>" + questions[i].answers[1].text + "</button>");
            if (questions[i].answers.length > 1)
                document.write("<button id = 'answer3' onclick = 'next(questions[i].answers[2].correct)'>" + questions[i].answers[2].text + "</button>");
            if (questions[i].answers.length > 2)
                document.write("<button id = 'answer4' onclick = 'next(questions[i].answers[3].correct)'>" + questions[i].answers[3].text + "</button>");
        }

        // go to next question, marking whether answer was right or wrong
        function next(correct) {
            if(correct) progress[i] = "T";
            else progress[i] = "F";
            i += 1;
            display(i);
        }
```

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle displaying the problem?

Comment: too long; didn't read...

Comment: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tTP8z/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read through your code, (you might want to work on posting [SSCCEs](http://sscce.org/) by focusing just on the part that handles the loop) but I get the feeling a loop is not what you want here. Loops are great if you need to automatically iterate through something. But really, you want to display only a single question at a time.

The easiest way to do this, assuming you have a means of handling each question independently, is just to keep track of which question the user is up to.  Display that question.  When the user submits an answer, call whatever function renders a question using the counter, plus one.  Make sure to check that you haven't hit the end of the quiz so that you don't reference a question that doesn't exist.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
var questionNumber, questions; //assume these already have values
function printQuestion(questionNumber){ ... }
function nextQuestion(){
    if(questionNumber < questions){
         questionNumber++;
         printQuestion(questionNumber); 
    }
    else{
         showResults();
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that, and it doesn't work properly...although come to think of it, maybe you can help me fix that. I'll post it.

Comment: @fawfulfan Try to focus just the part of the code that you think is failing. For example, if it's not printing, show us the print code. If  its printing the *same* question, show us the nextQuestion-esque code

Comment: There, I've revised the code to be more like what you said, although this still doesn't work, and I don't understand why. When you click a button, nothing happens. What's wrong with my function calls?

Comment: @fawfulfan I'm sorry, I don't see any obvious problems. Are there any Javascript errors? Have you tried debugging it? The Javascript console in Chrome has a great debugger for walking through your code line by line

Comment: I have no idea how to use the debugger. So, you don't have any ideas on why the onclick function isn't working?

Comment: @fawfulfan Odds are something isn't hooked up right. A variable is falling out of scope, a typo, etc. Far too many options. Learning the debugger is perhaps one of the *most* important skills as a programmer, and it's super easy. There's plenty SO posts and tutorials on it. Do that first, and when you discover what's breaking come back or make a new question about that specifically and SO will be able to help better

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ngmiceli that a loop isn't what you want here. You want to display one question, and then create click event handlers that will move on to the next question when the user selects an answer to the previous question.

I went ahead and created a different setup to demonstrate. You can see a demo here:

[**-- jsFiddle DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/ppp9Z/)

But I'll walk through the process. First, I set up a basic HTML document:

```
<body>
    <h1>-Test v1-</h1>
    <h2>Simple Math</h2>
    <div id="container">
        <div><span id="numRight">0</span> of <span id="numQuestions">0</span></div>
        <div id="question"></div>
        <div id="answers"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then, I created a questions `array`, each element in the array being an `object`. Each question object contains the question itself, an array of possible answers, and an "answerIdx" property that indicates the array index of the correct answer.

```
questions = [
    {
        question: 'What is 0 / 6 ?',
        options: ['0','1','2'],
        answerIdx: 0
    },
    {
        question: 'What is 2 + 2 ?',
        options: ['72','4','3.5'],
        answerIdx: 1
    }
]
```

I also created some other variables that point to the HTML elements I am going to want to manipulate:

```
numRight = 0,
numQuestions = 0,
answerDiv = document.getElementById('answers'),
questionDiv = document.getElementById('question'),
numRightSpan = document.getElementById('numRight'),
numQuestionsSpan = document.getElementById('numQuestions');
```

Next, I created a 'displayQuestion' function which takes a single question object as a parameter:

```
function displayQuestion(q) {  
    // insert the question text into the appropriate HTML element
    questionDiv.innerHTML = q.question;

    // remove any pre-existing answer buttons
    answerDiv.innerHTML = '';

    // for each option in the 'options' array, create a button
    // attach an 'onclick' event handler that will update
    // the question counts and display the next question in the array
    for(i = 0; i < q.options.length; i++) {
        btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.innerHTML = q.options[i];
        btn.setAttribute('id',i);

        // event handler for each answer button
        btn.onclick = function() {
            var id = parseInt(this.getAttribute('id'),10);
            numQuestionsSpan.innerHTML = ++numQuestions;

            // if this is the right answer, increment numRight
            if(id === q.answerIdx) {
                numRightSpan.innerHTML = ++numRight;
            }

            // if there is another question to be asked, run the function again
            // otherwise, complete the test however you see fit
            if(questions.length) {
                displayQuestion(questions.shift()); 
            } else {
                alert('Done! You got '+numRight+' of '+numQuestions+' right!');
            }                    
        }
        answerDiv.appendChild(btn);        
    }
}
```

Finally, I displayed the first question:

```
displayQuestion(questions.shift());
```

Comment: Okay, now I've managed to make the buttons react when I click. But the problem now is that none of the divs are recreated after you click the buttons...it just displays plain old text and buttons. Why isn't document.write() working for divs the second time?